# After tableView scrolled data puts in cells in wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

in my View:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TransactionTableCell", for: indexPath) as! TransactionTableCell
            let newItem = getTransactionsInSection(section: sectionHeader[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row]
            cell.configure(item: newItem)
}
```

in my TransactionTableCell

```
    func configure(item: TransactionModel) {
        
        guard let withdrawalBonuses = item.withdrawalBonuses,
              withdrawalBonuses < 0,
              let accruedBonuses = item.accruedBonuses,
              accruedBonuses > 0 else {
                  configureWithOneOperation(item)//shows one line of operation
                  return
              }

//show 2 lines of operations

        firstOperationAmountLabel.text = "+\(Int(accruedBonuses))"
        secondOperationAmountLabel.text = "\(Int(withdrawalBonuses))"
}
```

When I scroll the cell , second operation line is appears in wrong cells where its shouldn't be, even If I reload my table , that also has this problem.

Comment: in case your cells are reused when scrolling, data from previous occurrences still might be displayed. You always should override all fields when configuring your cell with new data. This might be prevented by the `guard`statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **prepareForReuse()** method

Simply just clear data of your labels:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    firstOperationAmountLabel.text = nil
    secondOperationAmountLabel.text = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to check here.

- Make sure you reset all fields before configure a new cell.
- If you have created a cell using xib or storyboard, make sure you haven't filled labels with static text.
- Is your guard statements passing for every item?
- Else block for guard configures cell with a single operation, Is it handling all ui elements in cell?